# X Image following cursor mouse pointer

Tags: x11, mouse, cursor

i have rpi connected with hdmi on big tv few meters from my workplace and i want to change size of mouse pointer.

xsetroot -mouse .. .. will change just one type of cursor and not covering all situations.

How to load my custom image above all windows in any window manager, to follow mouse movements over all programs and xterms ...

Preferred is some tool that is part of X-org, but short script or C-source lines would be ok too.

... something like simplified-as-possible version of [ONEKO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neko_(computer_program)) game.

Comment: I assume you want the background image to change as normal, rather than be a static image?

Comment: @JoeSewell static image (transparent png or bmp+mask) to draw for example big 2 inch size (or ~300px) target cross arround cursor, like target in counter-strike :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late to the game, but just spotted this [Large software cursor for screen recording on X11](https://github.com/andykitchen/swcursor) repo and I think it does what you want. If you still care nearly 8 years later : D